# Android 4.0 Support for Action Bar Up Navigation

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I followed the Tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home and I added the latest android-support-v4.jar to my Project. I also added the jar-file to my Buildpath. I modified my Manifest.xml file and anything works fine for Android 4.1.2. But if I use Android 4.0.4 the Back buttons are shown but they didn't respond. Did anyone had the same problem?

Best regards

Martin

Comment: can you show the activity Manifest XML tag?

Comment: <activity android:name=".ProjectListActivity">  
                
<activity android:name=".ControlMenuActivity"   
              android:parentActivityName=".ProjectListActivity" >
          
<meta-data      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"      android:value=".ProjectListActivity" />

Comment: Is the first activity xml tag closed?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem depends on the related android-support-v4.jar, but I don't know whats wrong in there. Do I have to include that jar in my java code?

Comment: Yes. Put it in libs folder and make sure it is checked in exported tab in project properties

Comment: hmm do I have to include something else? the jar is in the lib folder and it is already checked in the exported tab?